# How to get a certain characters through regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the following string:

```
   uri=/abc/jkncedknj/dslkmfldsmf/245?X_Security_Token=o93457yndo49758yewrwet&accountId=bob123
```

I want to essentially obfuscate the `x_secuirty_token`, so essentially delete all but 4 characters in the string: `o93457yndo49758yewrwet`

Currently I'm following these steps to achieve it:

- find the token within the string
- extract it from the string
- get the first four digits of the token and place it back in the string

The strings are dynamic so I'm essentially looking into replacing anything from the `=` after the `X_Security_Token` to `&accountId=bob123`

I've tried the following:

`[Token][=]{a-zA-z0-9}+[&accountId]` but it's complaining that the syntax would be incorrect. I've tried other variations but it still doesn't work. I'm pretty new to regex.

Comment: You just use `X_Security_Token=[^&]*` to match the query param with its value. `[&accountId]` matches a single char, either `&`, or `a`, or `c`, or `u`... and `{a-zA-z0-9}` is a completely messed part that should have been written as `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Comment: Thanks for this. The `X_Security_Token=[^&]*` captures the following:
`X_Security_Token=o93457yndo49758yewrwet`. I jsut want `o93457yndo49758yewrwet`. Any ideas?

Comment: Sure, capture it, `X_Security_Token=([^&]*)` and grab Group 1 value. Or use a lookbehind, `(?<=X_Security_Token=)[^&]*`